# Isotope filter by tag href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm using jquery isotope and the filter data work great by I also need to filter by href tags.

**html**

```
<a id="bmw" href="#bmw" data-filter=".bmw" class="btn btn-green">Bmw Car</a> 
<a id="audi" href="#audi" data-filter=".audi" class="btn btn-green">Audi Car</a>
```

So when client enter in url : www.test.ro/#bmw It needs to filter only data for bmw car as is working when the button is clicked.

**jquery**

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($)
{
    var $container = $('#container-folio');

    if ($container.length)
    {
        $container.waitForImages(function()
        {
            // initialize isotope
            $container.isotope(
            {
                itemSelector: '.box',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });
            // filter items when filter link is clicked
            $('#filters a').click(function()
            {
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope(
                {
                    filter: selector
                });
                $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active all');
                return false;
            });
        }, null, true);

        // hash code filter
        $(window).load(function()
        {
            // Store # parameter and add "." before hash
            var hashID = "." + window.location.hash.substring(1);
            // console.log(hashID);
            //  the current version of isotope, the hack works in v2 also
            if (hashID != '.form')
            {
                var $container = $('#container-folio');
                $container.imagesLoaded(function()
                {
                    $container.isotope(
                    {
                        itemSelector: ".box",
                        filter: hashID, // the variable filter hack
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Tried the code above for filter hash but didn't worked, any ideas ?

Comment: Please provide to us a MCVE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve